# Check namespaces relative to folder in solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to create a `DiagnosticAnalyzer` that detects when a namespace declaration is different from the directory location in a project in VS.

Example:

```
Solution
  - Project
     - ProjectFolder
        - MyClass.cs

namespace Project.ProjectFolder // Good
namespace Project.OtherSubNamespace // Bad, different from the location
```

The problem I'm facing right now, is to find the source path (relative to the project) from the current SymbolAnalysisContext in the analyzer. In a codefix provider, you would use the `Document` class, but I'm not sure if it's possible from a `SymbolAnalysisContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DeclaringSyntaxReferences` property](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,147) of the symbol being analyzed.

Note that there may be zero, or two or more, references.

Comment: I see, with that, I can get the source file's path. But is there a way I can get the current solution directory? With this information, I could make the path relative and check if the relative path corresponds to the namespace. I really only need the project path of the source file!

Comment: Not easily, because analyzers can run below the solution layer (and outside VS)

Comment: You might be able to grab the VisualStudioWorkspace from the VS global ServiceProvider via MEF, but it would be hacky.